# SQL group functions using joins

Tags: sql, function, join

Problem: 
Create a list of department names, the manager id, 
manager name (employee last name) of that department, and the average salary in each 
department.

```
SELECT d.department_name, d.manager_id, AVG(e.salary)
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY d.department_name, d.manager_id;
```

And it works nice, but when I add the `e.last_name`, I get all the last names from employees table.

I do believe the answer to be out here and not quite far, although out of my reach at this point.

Comment: All last names is what you are selecting by e.last_name. Could you please offer some hints on what your data/tables look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pull the name of the manager, you need to join `employees` again, this time on `d.manager_id`:

```
SELECT d.department_name, d.manager_id, m.name, AVG(e.salary)
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (m.employee_id = d.manager_id)
GROUP BY d.department_name, d.manager_id, m.name;
```

The kind of join (inner or outer) is not essential here, because you group by `d.manager_id`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to join `d.manager_id` to `employees` again to get the managers `last_name`:

```
SELECT d.department_name, d.manager_id, e2.last_name, AVG(e.salary)
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
INNER JOIN employees e2 ON d.manager_id = e2.employee_id
GROUP BY d.department_name, d.manager_id, e2.last_name
```

Comment: Don't you think it's more about adding it to the group by expression than joining once more?

Comment: No, from what I gathered the OP wanted the last name of the Manager.  To get that you would have to link to the employee table again.  Just using `e.last_name` would give you the last name of each employee.